# Get Selected values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to compare datetimes and delete the rows thats more than 72 hours old. Then I want to update another table boolean "HasClone". How do I get the ints (ID's) from the first selection into the other? see code below:

```
 SELECT Allocation_plan_details_Clone.Allocation_plan_id AS ID
         FROM Allocation_plan_details_Clone
         WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, GETDATE()) > 72
         UPDATE Allocation_plan
         SET HasClone = 0
         WHERE allocation_plan_id = <INSERT CODE HERE!>
         DELETE FROM Allocation_plan_details_Clone
         WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, GETDATE()) > 72
```

So at "INSERT CODE HERE!" I want to insert the ID's I just got from Allocation_plan_details_Clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question right I think what you want is this:

```
UPDATE Allocation_plan
SET HasClone = 0
WHERE allocation_plan_id IN (
    SELECT Allocation_plan_details_Clone.Allocation_plan_id
    FROM Allocation_plan_details_Clone
    WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, GETDATE()) > 72
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is putting the Allocation_plan_id's into a table variable while the rows are deleted.

The transaction assure that the data doesn't get deleted without updating the Allocation_plan table.

I rewrote your WHERE statement to perform better.

```
begin transaction t

DECLARE @deleted table(Allocation_plan_id int)

DELETE Allocation_plan_details_Clone
OUTPUT deleted.Allocation_plan_id
INTO @deleted
FROM Allocation_plan_details_Clone
WHERE start_date < dateadd(hour, -72, GETDATE())

UPDATE Allocation_plan
SET HasClone = 0
FROM Allocation_plan
JOIN
@deleted d
ON d.Allocation_plan_id = Allocation_plan.Allocation_plan_id

commit transaction t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you could just make a temp table (that resides on that database connection and deletes itself as soon as you drop the connection.

It would go something like this:

```
SELECT Allocation_plan_details_Clone.Allocation_plan_id AS ID INTO #temp_table
         FROM Allocation_plan_details_Clone
         WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, GETDATE()) > 72
         UPDATE Allocation_plan
         SET HasClone = 0
         WHERE allocation_plan_id = <INSERT CODE HERE!>
         DELETE FROM Allocation_plan_details_Clone
         WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, GETDATE()) > 72
;
```

Then you can do whatever you want with this temp table such as:

```
delete
from other_table
where id in (select id from #temp_table)
;
```

note: Not sure the DBMS you are running on, however MSSQL has a hashtag that refers to temporary tables. Postgres I don't think you need to do this and not sure about other DBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use temp table to hold the IDS you want, it will be like this

```
SELECT Allocation_plan_details_Clone.Allocation_plan_id AS ID
into #TempTable
FROM Allocation_plan_details_Clone
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, GETDATE()) > 72

UPDATE a
SET HasClone = 0
WHERE allocation_plan_id in (select ID from #TempTable)

DELETE FROM Allocation_plan_details_Clone
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, GETDATE()) > 72
```